# can´t remove separation between frames inside a stacklayout in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

For some reason even with margin and padding equals to 0, there is still a separation between the elements. Have an idea?
 This is the image

[imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGftX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what 'separation' means from the picture.
But it looks like you need to **flatten** your frames or remove the **shadows**, while removing **spacing** from the StackLayout.

*I am using Styles to set other Frame properties.*

```
           <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
                <StackLayout.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Frame">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                    </Style>
                </StackLayout.Resources>

                <Frame HasShadow="False"/>
                <Frame HasShadow="False"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: the problem was to remove the shadows, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You want the Spacing property. Try setting Spacing to 0. The default value is 6.
Link to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stacklayout.spacing?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: I was already using spacing=0, thanks for the help and sorry for answer until now